# UIActivityIndicatorView inside UINavigatorBar | Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview, uinavigationitem

I would like to add an UIActivityIndicatorView (_av object) object into a left bar button item of UINavigationItem

My code looks like :

```
UIBarButtonItem * button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_av];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:button];
[button release];
```

but after I launch the code I take an error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationBar layoutSublayersOfLayer:],    /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5776
```

2013-04-15 16:28:39.246 *** [12484:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UINavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

How I should to implement it correctly ?